# how to model this relationship in Spine.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, spine.js

in my app i would need to model a relationship between objects that is very similar to a filesystem.

i have `Image`, `Video` and `Collection`

Collections can contain all of the three type of Objects. 
while a Image and Video can be part of multiple Collections, the Collection can only be contained in one (1) Collection.

what is the best way to model this kind of relationship in spine?

what i thought to do is make everything sublclass from one generic model definition, lets say Asset
so everything is an Asset and i can implement class and instancemethods on that model and all subclassed model definitions inherit those methods.

the problem i encountered with this approach is that i would need/like to put the relationship on Asset so

```
class Asset extends Spine.Model
    @configure 'Asset', 'title', 'description'

    @belongsTo 'collection', Collection
```

besides the fact that i am not sure if this actually works if i have Colletion subclass Asset and asset sets a reference to Collection...
the problem here is that belongsTo is a one way relation, and i need this only for Collections
so the right way would be to have a `@hasMany 'collections', Collection` and be sure no collection sets more than one object to this property

another question is: can i use Asset.find(id) to get all objects that are a subclass of Asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your problem is, other than trying out if your above structure works.

What you're describing is known as the 'composite design pattern' ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern ) where `Collection` is the 'composite' and both `Image` and `Video` are the 'leafs'

Relating to your `@hasMany` question, wouldn't you want the following instead of `@hasMany 'collections', Collection` on your `Collection` subclass, in addition to the `Asset` code you already defined:

`@hasMany 'assets', Asset`

Given that you could traverse up and down the tree.

Again, I'm really not sure if such recursive traversal works in Spine (never tried it, although I use Spine extensively)

hth some, 
Geert-Jan

Comment: yes the composite pattern is what im trying to implement. i had issues when subclassing/extending the Asset model (`Spine.Model`) because it did not bring all properties by simply subclassing it... i had to do a `@extend Asset` within the model definition. another issue i encountered is that i tried to put the relation (belongsTo or hasMany) to Collection on the Asset and here i got another error i couldn't figure out (it might be because Collection is a subclass of asset but i don't know.

Comment: not sure what you are suggesting with the `@hasMany 'assets', Asset`, you mean i should implement a hasMany for assets and collections?

Comment: well to build the composite pattern (again, you have to check out for yourself if this recursive stuff works in Spine) you'd have: 1) `@belongsTo 'collection', 'Collection'` on `Asset` and 2)  `@hasMany 'assets', Asset` on `Collection` . These definitions should go together as they form the 2 sides of a bidirectional relation between `Asset` and `Collection`. This enables a `Collection` to have many `Assets` among which `Image` and `Video` but also `Collection` which allows for arbitrary deeply nested collections, e.g: `col1 > colb > colc > videoA`

Comment: ok. the thing is also that a Video and Image could be part or multiple collections and not only one but thats not the issue atm. ill figure out what to do. thank you!